# How to run "adb commands" from UIAutomator

Tags: android, scripting, adb, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

So I have a UIAutomator test script and I during the execution of the test I want it to run some adb commands. How do I do this ?

I am thinking is there a way to call a script inside the UI automator class ? or is there a way to execute the "adb commands" directly ?

This is the code I have:

```
package com.uia.example.my;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class ADBCommandTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase{
    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException{

        System.out.println("Entering the shell script");
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./run.sh");
            Process p = pb.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null; 
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

And this is the error I get:

```
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.uia.example.my.ADBCommandTest
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
com.uia.example.my.ADBCommandTest:
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 1
Entering the shell script
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [./run.sh] Working Directory: null Environment: [EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE=/mnt/shell/emulated, SECONDARY_STORAGE=/storage/sdcard1, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/storage/emulated/legacy, CUSTOM_NOTIFICATION_MANAGER_SERVICE=com.amazon.device.notification.AmazonNotificationManagerService, LD_PRELOAD=/vendor/lib/libNimsWrap.so, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/telephony-msim.jar:/system/framework/DeviceClientMetrics-Api.jar:/system/framework/acos-util.jar:/system/framework/acosservices.jar:/system/framework/acos-core.jar:/system/framework/icu4j.jar:/system/framework/i18n-utilities.jar:/system/framework/amazon.core.jar:/system/framework/amazon-search.jar:/system/framework/qcmediaplayer.jar:/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar:/system/framework/oem-services.jar:/system/framework/dolby_ds.jar:/system/framework/com.amazon.headtracking.jar:/system/framework/com.amazon.motiongestures.jar:/system/framework/com.amazon.headtracking.filter.jar:/system/framework/eaclibrary.jar:/system/framework/euclidlibrary.jar:/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar, ANDROID_SOCKET_adbd=10, EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET=/storage/emulated, RANDOM=20395, AMAZON_COMPONENT_LIST=com.amazon.geo.maps:com.amazon.platform;com.amazon.device.messaging:com.amazon.platform, _=/system/bin/app_process, ANDROID_DATA=/data/local/tmp, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, ANDROID_STORAGE=/storage, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, CLASSPATH=/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar:/system/framework/uiautomator.jar::/data/local/tmp/ADBCommandTest.jar, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, GCOV_PREFIX=/data/gcov, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, run_base=/data/local/tmp, base=/system, VENDOR_SERVICES_LIST=tyto.vibrator.VibratorService:com.amazon.client.metrics.AndroidMetricsFactoryImpl:amazon.communication.SingleRequestResponseManagerService:amazon.communication.CommunicationManagerService:com.amazon.device.nos.NetworkOptimizationManagerImpl:amazon.profile.ProfileManager:com.amazon.communication.ByteAccountantService, AMAZON_EXTRA_RESOURCE_LIST=framework/amazon-res.apk:vendor/amazon/framework/framework-res.apk:framework/amazon-b-res.apk:framework/euclid-res.apk, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=9,66048]
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:195)
    at com.uia.example.my.ADBCommandTest.testDemo(ADBCommandTest.java:17)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:168)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.start(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:144)
    at com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestRunner.run(UiAutomatorTestRunner.java:87)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.RunTestCommand.run(RunTestCommand.java:90)
    at com.android.commands.uiautomator.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:83)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
    ... 17 more
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=com.uia.example.my.ADBCommandTest
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testDemo
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
Time: 0.042

OK (1 test)


INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
```

I placed the run.sh script file in the same place where my class files are. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that works. I have copied the script file "command.sh" to external SDcard before running the UiAutomator test.

The code does not require any root permissions.

```
package ui;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class SampleCode extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
    public void testHome() throws RemoteException,
        UiObjectNotFoundException {

    // press Home
    UiDevice mydevice = getUiDevice();
    if (!mydevice.isScreenOn()) {
        mydevice.wakeUp();
    }
    mydevice.pressHome();

    // Script path
    String filePath = "/mnt/sdcard_ext/command.sh";
    File command = new File(filePath);
    command.setExecutable(true);

    // Run command
    Process p = null;       
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "/system/bin/sh /mnt/sdcard_ext/command.sh");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (p != null)
            p.destroy();
    }

 }
```

}

Here is the content of "command.sh", output will be written to a file on the external SDcard

```
SDCARD="/mnt/sdcard_ext/"
LOG="$SDCARD/testlog.txt"
logcat -d >> $LOG
```

Answer (score 21):

I previously used to inject shell commands in test setUp()/tearDown() using the runtime method, but it stopped working for me when I switched to UIAutomator 2.0 and Gradle.

If you're fine with using API 21 (lollipop) and above, Google provides this API for us:

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getUiAutomation().executeShellCommand("pm clear " + Constants.PACKAGE_NAME);
```

This method works for my use case. Source:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiAutomation.html#executeShellCommand(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Try this method-

```
public String shell(String cmd) {

    String s = null;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getErrorStream()));

        // read the output from the cmd
        String result = "";
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result + s + "\n";
        }

        // read any errors from the attempted comd
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        return result;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception here's what I know: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Exception occurred";
    }
}
```

Now you call-

```
String ls= Shell("ls");
```